# Shouldn't Eclipse parser detect find this kind of IndexOutOfBounds exceptions?

Tags: java, eclipse

Assume this code:

```
String[] data = new String[2];
data[0] = "OK";
data[1] = "returning data";
data[2] = "data out of bounds";
```

For sure will throw an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.

My question is:

- There is some reason because `Eclipse` parser does not complain this issue with a `warning` or an `error`?

Analizing the case I find:

- It's easy to detect.
- Will avoid lots of useless launches.

There are other similar warnings/errors being detected like:

- `uninitialized variable` when you try to use a variable declared as `List<String> = null`.
- `unreachable code` when writting sentences after a valid `return`.
- `unused code` in the dead branches of `if` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other cases that you mentioned are not directly related:

- An **uninitialized variable** is a plain compile-time error, according to [JLS Chapter 16, "Definite Assignment"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html).
- The **unreachable code** is a compile-time error as well, according to [JLS Section 14.21, "Unreachable Statements"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21)

The last remaining one is the **dead code**. This is *not* an error, and the reasons are also explained in the [Unreachable Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) section:

> One might expect the if statement to be handled in the following manner:
>
> ...
>
> This approach would be consistent with the treatment of other control structures. However, in order to allow the if statement to be used conveniently for "conditional compilation" purposes, the actual rules differ.
>
> As an example, the following statement results in a compile-time error:
>
> ```
> while (false) { x=3; }
> ```
>
> because the statement x=3; is not reachable; but the superficially similar > case:
>
> ```
> if (false) { x=3; }
> ```
>
> does not result in a compile-time error. An optimizing compiler may realize that the statement x=3; will never be executed and may choose to omit the code for that statement from the generated class file, but the statement x=3; is not regarded as "unreachable" in the technical sense specified here.

So the "dead code" is "unusual" and certainly something that is worth pointing out, but not necessarily an error.

---

Regarding your actual question (ignoring the fact that the Parser and the Compiler are two different things - it's clear what the question was about): This is a very specific case. It only applies when the declaration of the array and the access to the array are in the same scope. Additionally, the indices must be compile-time constants.

So obviously, it would not be possible for

```
void init(String data[]) {
    data[0] = "OK";
    data[1] = "returning data";
    data[2] = "data out of bounds";    
}
```

or

```
int i = 0;
data[i++] = "OK";
data[i++] = "returning data";
data[i++] = "data out of bounds";
```

There probably is no convincing, profound reason of why this is not detected by Eclipse, except that the ratio between the effort of detecting such bugs and the benefit is not sufficiently high - so maybe something like this will be added in a future release. There already are some rather sophisticated warnings in Eclipse (e.g. automatic detection of "Null pointer access"). But for a more detailed, static analysis, there are dedicated tools, like [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net) or [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/), which take greater effort (and more time, by the way) than the tests that are done casually and on the fly by eclipse.

---

A side note: You can consider avoiding this kind of bug with

```
String data[] = {
    "OK",
    "returning data",
    "data out of bounds"
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can install a [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) plugin for Eclipse (available on Eclipse marketplace). It's capable to detect such problem:

[image: FindBugs warning]

Comment: Thanks @Tagir. I know and use FindBugs, but my question is actually, why eclipse does not warns us about this visible issue... when it does with others

Comment: @JordiCastilla, I guess because it just wasn't done (you can implement it and propose a patch). Also such analysis may slow down the development. What if `data` is assigned several times? What if a variable with known value is used as array index or array length? FindBugs can detect some of such cases as well, but FindBugs analysis is much slower than Eclipse analysis. So you can decide whether you want cheap and fast static analysis or slow, but more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

> There is some reason because Eclipse parser does not complain this issue with a warning or an error?

Eclipse doesn't give you an error message because this is valid Java code, according to the Java language specification.  If Eclipse treated that as an compilation error, it would not be a proper Java compiler.

The warning case is less clear cut.  Yes, Eclipse could (legitimately) provide a warning, much like it warns about some cases involving NPEs.  However, there is a trade-off between producing helpful warnings, and the time that the compiler spends checking for the conditions that give rise to them.  Too much checking will make the compiler slower for all programs, and programmers will complain about *that*.  (Especially programmers who work on applications with thousands of classes.)

As @Tagir notes, if you want to be warned about this kind of thing, consider using a bug checker such as FindBugs or PMD.

---

> There are other similar warnings/errors being detected like ...

The two of three cases that you listed are all compilation errors because the Java Language Specification states that they are invalid Java code.  I'm not sure about the "dead code" case because it is unclear what case you are referring to.  If you are referring to

```
if (<compile-time-constant-expr>) { ... } else { ... }
```

then that code *shouldn't* give either a compilation error or a warning.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't Eclipse parser detect find this kind of IndexOutOfBounds
>   exceptions?

Obviously the answer is yes since it is easy to detect.

But you can also do better and avoid the potential error by not using a magic constant:

```
String[] data = new String[] { "OK", "returning data", "data not out of bounds" };
```

Comment: this is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), of course here you can declare array directly, but it's just a way to show why I have this question. My concrete case is **a)** much longer and complex, **b)** I can't change from `array` to `List` **c)** data is filled dinamically btw database / server / view **d)** array lenght grows each time customer has new requirements...

Comment: @JordiCastilla: If your initialization is more complex as you showed the code analysis for the compiler could also be more complex leading to bigger compilation times. And that's not something I would buy any longer.